# How to use python pandas to combine the same name into one, without removing other columns

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, multi-index

Here is the example

```
    name        year     date      start opp
0   A.J. Price  2015     2014-12-02 No  MIL
1   A.J. Price  2015     2014-12-04 No  NYK
2   A.J. Price  2015     2014-12-05 No  TOR
3   A.J. Price  2015     2014-12-08 No  BRK
4   A.J. Price  2015     2014-12-09 No  TOR
318 Aaron       2015     2014-12-15 No  ATL
319 Aaron       2015     2014-12-18 No  NYK
320 Aaron       2015     2014-12-19 No  MEM
```

How to make the data frame above into something hierarchy like below

```
0   A.J. Price  2015     2014-12-02 No  MIL
                2015     2014-12-04 No  NYK
                2015     2014-12-05 No  TOR 
                2015     2014-12-08 No  BRK
                2015     2014-12-09 No  TOR  
318 Aaron       2015     2014-12-15 No  ATL
                2015     2014-12-18 No  NYK
                2015     2014-12-19 No  MEM
```

Comment: IIUC then `df.set_index('name', append=True, inplace=True)` should work, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

With the help given by [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) here is how it can be done:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   name         year       date        start  opp
0  A.J. Price      2015    2014-12-02   No    MIL
1  A.J. Price      2015    2014-12-04   No    NYK
2  A.J. Price      2015    2014-12-05   No    TOR
3  A.J. Price      2015    2014-12-08   No    BRK
4  A.J. Price      2015    2014-12-09   No    TOR
5  Aaron           2015    2014-12-15   No    ATL
6  Aaron           2015    2014-12-18   No    NYK
7  Aaron           2015    2014-12-19   No    MEM

In [12]: df.set_index('name',inplace=True)
In [13]: df.set_index('year',append=True, inplace=True)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                          date  start  opp
name        year
A.J. Price  2015    2014-12-02   No    MIL
            2015    2014-12-04   No    NYK
            2015    2014-12-05   No    TOR
            2015    2014-12-08   No    BRK
            2015    2014-12-09   No    TOR
Aaron       2015    2014-12-15   No    ATL
            2015    2014-12-18   No    NYK
            2015    2014-12-19   No    MEM
```

> Update:

While writing out multi-index tables (or pivot_tables) to_csv will write the hierarchical index of each row, resulting in data as follows:

[image]

However using to_excel will write the output like this by merging the rows of hierarchical index:

[image]

So if the concern is how to get back the multi-index while reading the csv back, use the `index_col` argument of the function:

```
pd.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=[0,1])
```

Here is another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv) that will help you to write the csv the way you wanted.

Comment: This works in the console (print df). But when I output this dataframe to csv file (df.to_csv), all the repeated names are still there in csv.