# Pandas Multiindex to CSV without duplicate Index

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

For the life of me I can't figure out how to remove the duplicate index items created when writing a multiindex dataframe to CSV. While there is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv) out there, it doesn't apply to me per se because my second level has all different values.

This is a chunk of the dataframe I have, it just goes on for each month

```
Month Measure
JAN   KWH          
      Max KW       
      Day/Hour     
      Peak End Use 
      Peak Pct     
FEB   KWH          
      Max KW       
      Day/Hour     
      Peak End Use 
      Peak Pct
```

But in CSV it looks something like

```
JAN KWH
JAN Max KW
JAN Day/Hour
JAN Peak End Use
JAN Peak Pct
FEB KWH
FEB Max KW
FEB Day/Hour
FEB Peak End Use
FEB Peak Pct
```

I hope for it to look exactly just like the dataframe so that means in CSV it would look like

```
Jan,KWH
   ,Max KW
   ,Day/Hour

and so on
```

I have tried  `df.index.to_series().duplicates()` but it doesn't work because each of my index pairs are not duplicates. I've also tried using `index.tolist()` then looping through to change with no luck.

What's the right approach here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an expected CSV output? The index would be the combination of the first and second columns and what you've shown is that exactly, so I don't see any duplicates.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear. I had hoped that the output would look exactly like how the dataframe does where there's only one of first index and multiple of the other.

Comment: I think if you write it that way, you will no longer have a recognizable CSV file. That is, if you were to write to your multi-index CSV format, then read that CSV file, it would give you a totally different result. That is what most of the answer you linked seems to address -- how to get Pandas to read the file and format as expected.

Comment: I won't be reading it back with the script at all. All I want is to be extracting certain information from a few thousand page long simulation out put. The first character can just be a space no?

Comment: Ah. Got it. Then it's much simpler than you think. You can just use `file.write(str(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pandas does not provide directly such functionality, perhaps to ensure that the generated csv files can be read back, as mentioned in the comments above. I faced with the same problem when generating a table for report in rst format. Finally, I decided to process the generated csv by an external script. The [script](https://gist.github.com/travleev/729b49fea6a1938d289205b09f199074) replaces the repeating values in columns with spaces, thus achieving desired result. Note: this script assumes commas as csv separators.

```
# Clean csv with multiindices
from sys import argv

# Positional command line arguments:
#   1: original csv file
#   2: number of columns to check (optional)

with open(argv[1], 'r') as f:
  if len(argv) > 2:
    n = int(argv[2])
    i0 = ('', ) * n
  else:
    n = None
    i0 = None
  for l in f:
    if n is None:
        # define n from the 1-st line
        i1 = l.split(',')
        n = len(i1)
        i0 = ('', ) * n
    i1 = l.split(',', n)
    nl = ()
    for s0, s1 in zip(i0, i1):
        if s0 == s1:
            e = ' ' * len(s0)
        else:
            e = s1
        nl += (e, )
    nl += tuple(i1[n:])
    print ','.join(nl),
    i0 = i1[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer to a newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64381635/2502831), you can move the index levels to columns and use [DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to set duplicate index values to NaN:

```
def prepare_multiindex_for_export(df):
  new_df = df.copy()

  for i in range(df.index.nlevels, 0, -1):
    new_df = new_df.sort_index(level=i-1)

  replace_cols = dict()
  
  for i in range(new_df.index.nlevels):
    idx = new_df.index.get_level_values(i)

    new_df.insert(i, idx.name, idx)

    replace_cols[idx.name] = new_df[idx.name].where(~new_df.duplicated(subset=new_df.index.names[:i+1]))

  for col, ser in replace_cols.items():
    new_df[col] = ser

  return new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'Last': 'Doe', 'First': 'John', 'Age': 43},
  {'Last': 'Doe', 'First': 'Jane', 'Age':42},
  {'Last': 'Blow', 'First': 'John', 'Age': 17},
  {'Last': 'Blow', 'First': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Last': 'Doe', 'First': 'Ben', 'Age': 30}]).set_index(['Last', 'First'])

>>> df
            Age
Last First
Doe  John    43
     Jane    42
Blow John    17
     Bob     20
Doe  Ben     30

>>> prepare_multiindex_for_export(df)
   Last First  Age
0  Blow   Bob   20
1   NaN  John   17
2   Doe   Ben   30
3   NaN  Jane   42
4   NaN  John   43

>>> print(prepare_multiindex_for_export(df).to_csv(index=False))
Last,First,Age
Blow,Bob,20
,John,17
Doe,Ben,30
,Jane,42
,John,43
```

Note: If your index has NaN values in it, you may need to modify