# Pandas multi-index to csv file

Tags: python, pandas

If I output multi-index dataframe to csv, why does my first index get repeated?

My dataframe:

```py
In [1]: \
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'index2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'column1': np.random.randint(2, size=8),
    'column2': np.random.randint(2, size=8),
    'column3': np.random.randint(2, size=8)
}).set_index(['index1', 'index2'])

Out[2]: \ 
print(df)
               column1  column2  column3
index1 index2                           
A      1             1        1        1
       2             0        1        1
       3             1        0        1
       4             0        0        0
B      1             0        1        0
       2             1        1        0
       3             0        0        0
       4             1        1        1
```

Below is what I get when I output dataframe as csv file.

Output (csv file):

```
                 column1   column2 column3
    index1  index2
    A         1       
    A         2
    A         3
    A         4
    B         1
    B         2
    B         3
    B         4
```

I want to output the csv file in the exact same format as the dataframe from first code snippet.

Comment: Because if you want to read it back, you need all the indices to do so consistently. Try reading a csv with blanks in a level of a multiindex. I bet you will get undesirable results.

Comment: [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv)

Answer (score 2):

The first index is repeated because that is what the data looks like under the hood, pandas just formats it that way to make it easier to read. When you call 'to_csv', the raw data is outputted. To do what you want you could reset the index and then replace duplicate values in that column with a blank.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.loc[df['index1'].duplicated(), 'index1'] = ''
df.to_csv('mycsv.csv', index=False)
```