# Removing specific data from an index in a CSV created by Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

My multi-index data frame is as so, which then gets converted through pandas built in to_csv() method.

```
                           Some Data fields
Frequency    VEQ   VCG
4000         0.9   0.3
4000         1.5   0.3
4000         0.9   0.4
4000         1.5   0.4
4000         0.9   0.5
5000         1.5   0.5
5000         0.9   0.6
5000         1.5   0.6
5000         0.9   0.7
5000         1.5   0.8
5000         0.9   0.9
6000         1.5   1.0
6000         0.9   1.1
6000         1.5   1.2
```

I'm looking to remove all the fields in the frequency column duplicate entries. For instance the created CSV should look like so:

```
                           Some Data fields
Frequency    VEQ   VCG
4000         0.9   0.3
             1.5   0.3
             0.9   0.4
             1.5   0.4
             0.9   0.5
5000         1.5   0.5
             0.9   0.6
             1.5   0.6
             0.9   0.7
             1.5   0.8
             0.9   0.9
6000         1.5   1.0
             0.9   1.1
             1.5   1.2
```

I am not sure if there is an elegant solution for this using the built in methods to Pandas, or if I should be possibly editing my CSV after the fact. I have tried

`df.index.set_level(df.index.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates, level=0)`

but when I convert to CSV I still run into the problem of the frequency values being populated in all rows of the respective indexing column.

Comment: Try the answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv

Comment: A work-around is to use `.to_excel` with the `merged_cells=True`