# Duplicate Values in inserted columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am adding some columns to a `df`. However in the `csv` , the inserted columns have duplicate data entries for all the rows in the inserted columns. When I use `drop_duplicates`. There is only 1 row in `csv`

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1').text
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="col-content"]//p[1]').text
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="event-status"]').text

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="table-main detail-odds sortable"]').get_attribute('outerHTML')
df = pd.read_html(table)[0]
row_drop = df[df['Bookmakers'].str.contains("Highest", na=False)].index.tolist()
df = df.iloc[:row_drop[0]+1]
df.insert(0,'Name', f'{name}')
df.insert(1,'Date', f'{date}')
df.insert(2,'Result',f'{result}')
df.to_csv(f'gambling/{name}.csv', index=False)
```

Current Output

```
Name  Date   Result
John  14th   computer
John  14th   arts
John  14th   commerce
```

Expected output

```
Name  Date  Result
John  14th  computer
            arts
            commerce
```

Comment: This is your csv output? The current output looks correct to me

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a straightforward solution. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17349769/9857631).

Comment: @AnuragDabas Would you like to add that as an answer? That worked. Perfect.

Comment: @AbhishekRai sure added **:)**

Comment: @AbhishekRai is this not tricky to read back in though for the reasons that not_speshal linked to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John'},
 'Date': {0: '14th', 1: '14th', 2: '14th'},
 'Result': {0: 'computer', 1: 'arts', 2: 'commerce'}})
```

try via `duplicated()` and `mask()` method:

```
df[['Name','Date']]=df[['Name','Date']].mask(df.duplicated(subset=['Name','Date']),'')
```

**OR**

via `duplicated()` and `where()` method:

```
df[['Name','Date']]=df[['Name','Date']].where(~df.duplicated(subset=['Name','Date']),'')
```

output of `df`:

```
    Name    Date    Result
0   John    14th    computer
1                   arts
2                   commerce
```

Comment: anyone who downvoted....why downvote? Kindly tell!!

Comment: I was checking the same thing...who downvoted my vote?