# Save sliced dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

my question is, if it is possible to save a sliced dataframe to a .csv file?
My dataframe is outputted in Jupyter Notebook like this:

```
  Value    Cluster    Keywords
    1           0       KW1, KW2
                        KW1, KW2, KW3
                        KW1
                1       KW1, KW2
                        KW1, KW2, KW3
                2       KW1
    2           0       
                0       .........
```

But when I try to save it to a CSV file with .to_csv, it looks like a regular dataframe:

```
Value    Cluster    Keywords
    1       0       KW1, KW2
    1       0       KW1, KW2, KW3
    1       0       KW1
    1       1       KW1, KW2
    1       1       KW1, KW2, KW3
    1       2       KW1
    2       0       
    2       0       .........
```

I would like to keep the format like above to make it easier to navigate through the CSV because it is quite lengthy. Are there any possibilities to do it?

**Edit:** Here the code snippet I tried

```
df = df.groupby(['Value', 'Cluster']).Keywords.sum().to_frame()
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=True)
```

**Edit to close this:**
As it does not seem to be possible to save a sliced dataframe to a csv file without losing the needed format, I figured out another way:

```
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - write Multiindex rows with to\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv)

Comment: could you give an code example? what did you try? From your example it is impossible to see what you actually tried.

Comment: No. it needs some value in the column, and you should be glad it is filling it for you.

Comment: @Zeitproblem sorry, I thought it was clear. I added the part that I think is relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fill the duplicated rows with empty string before exporting

```py
cols = ['Value', 'Cluster']

for col in cols:
    df.loc[df[col] == df[col].shift(), col] = ''
```

```
print(df)

  Value Cluster       Keywords
0     1       0       KW1, KW2
1                KW1, KW2, KW3
2                          KW1
3             1       KW1, KW2
4                KW1, KW2, KW3
5             2            KW1
6     2       0           None
7                         None
```

Comment: This works but be careful that when you read it back you need to fill the missing values and set the index again, do not expect it to be working with the MultiIndex out of the box (if you were using one)

Comment: @user2246849 `ffill` would work and OP hasn't mentioned MultiIndex.

Comment: Right, he hasn't mentioned it, mine was just a warning to OP not a critique to your answer.